# How can I link a Facebook photo to another website?

Tags: facebook, url, hyperlink, photo

e.g. When I upload a photo on my wall or in a comment, I want to add a link to the picture. So when a user clicks on that photo, it takes user to an external website link that I've added.

Comment: That is of course not possible

Comment: You can either put a URL in the photo description, or share a link that has the image set as thumbnail (Open Graph meta tags.)

Comment: But I've seen many people doing the same as I said.